# SQL remove duplicates considering only one column

Tags: sql

I'm not that experienced in SQL and facing a stupid problem. Also found some solutions on google but couldn't adapt these on my code.

The important part of my SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM a_table
WHERE ACTIVITY_TYPE = 'FORWARDED' or ACTIVITY_TYPE = 'ON_HOLD'
ORDER BY ORDERID DESC, ACTIVITY_TIME DESC, ACTIVITY_TYPE DESC;
```

Now I want use DISTINCT, but only on the column "ORDERID".
So I want to keep only the first row per ORDERID and remove all the following.

If I'm thinking at R, Python oder Power BI and how I could solve it there, I'm sure it cannot be that difficult, but I can't adapt it. I'm a bit lost...

Thank you very much for your help.

The result now looks like:

[image]

The wished result would be:

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: done, thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want one row per order id, then `ROW_NUMBER()` comes to mind:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDERID ORDER BY ACTIVITY_TIME DESC) as seqnum
      FROM a_table a
      WHERE ACTIVITY_TYPE IN ('FORWARDED', 'ON_HOLD')
     ) a
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```